# Using Iron Router to set a query variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to use Iron Router to call a page and filter results by the route. Effectively, the application allows you to create items. Items include an array that can have 0 to many tags:

```
Item: {
  _id: <assigned by application>,
  itemTags: []
}
```

The dropdown list on the navbar collects all tags from the items, does some cleaning, and then drops them into the dropdown menu:

```
// HTML

<template name="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Select List to View <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="/list/all-list-items">All List Items</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              {{#each uniqueTags}}
              <li><a href="/list/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

// JS

Template.header.helpers({
  uniqueTags: function() {
    var allItems = Items.find({checked: false});
    var uniqueTags = allItems.map((function(allItems) {return allItems.itemTags;}));
    uniqueTags = _.flatten(uniqueTags);
    uniqueTags = _.compact(uniqueTags);
    uniqueTags = _.uniq(uniqueTags);
    uniqueTags = _.sortBy(uniqueTags, function (name) {return name;});
    return uniqueTags;
  }
});
```

The router then sends you to "/list/". Everything up to this point works great. But then it falls apart. My problem is twofold:

1) How do I appropriately grab the data context of just the items that have the tag listed somewhere in the array?

2) How do I display those items on the "list" page? I have zero idea what should be in list.js to handle the returned data context

My current code is below, but it's hacked up and clearly not working :)

```
// JS - router.js

Router.route('/list/:tagName', {
  name: 'list',
  data: function() { 
    return Items.find({$and: [
      {checked: false}, {listItem: true}, {itemTags: {$in: ['this.params.tagName']}}
    ]});
  }
});

// HTML - list.html

<template name="list">
  <h3><span class="label label-default view-list">List</span></h3>
  {{#each listItems}}
    {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

// JS - list.js

Template.list.helpers({
  listItems: function() {
    <somehow use the returned data context>
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to process the data in helpers(list.js), You could process it in the router itself, and then use the handlebars to place it in template, You could create an object `data` with property `data.listItems` filled with `listItems` from router then you don't want the helper, then the `list.html` is okay

Comment: I don't think I do. I just have no idea how to process multiple returned items in the router and place them with spacebars. What would be the right way to write the router and the template so that all items returned get passed to {{#each <returned set of data>}}?

Comment: You could  write `someObject.listItems = Items.find({yourQuery}).fetch();` and then return it from the router to `list.html` template then the properties of each list item will be accessible like `{{tagText}}` what ever it is. The `listItem` property in the data returned from router will be like helper data

Comment: Do you want to list the tags in `itemTags` array of an item in `item` template, for every item matches that query in the router?

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
  Router.route('/list/:tagName', {
    name: 'list',
    data: function() { 
    return { 'listItems' : Items.find({$and: [
          {checked: false}, {listItem: true}, {itemTags: {$in: [this.params.tagName]}}
     ]}) };
   }
  });


// HTML - list.html

<template name="list">
  <h3><span class="label label-default view-list">List</span></h3>
 {{#each listItems}}
   {{> item}}
 {{/each}}
</template>
 // You have to write a item template 
// JS - list.js

Template.list.helpers({
  //listItems: function() {
  // this helper is not required
  // you could access the data by this.data.listItems
  //<somehow use the returned data context>
  //}
});
```

Comment: Your solution comes really close. I had to remove the single quotations around listItems in the `return` statement and from around `this.params.tagName` and then it worked. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I thought you were sure about the query and have doubt in placing it to template

Comment: I was good with the query to find the tags and put them in the dropdown list. And had the basic idea for finding the items. But returning the items was the big hurdle. The crux was the return of the spacebars reference.